# MST in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

there are prim and Kruskal algorithms to find mst in polynomial time 
I wonder, Are there any algorithms to find MST in a directed acyclic graph in linear time?

Comment: Can you define what a Spanning tree means for a DAG? I don't believe the concept is well defined. There is, however, the concept of a "spanning arborescence of minimum weight" which would work for not just DAGs but any Directed graph. An algorithm to find it is described in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm

Comment: Also, in general, linear time algorithms for anything to do with graphs need to be specified more exactly. For example, linear in the number of edges is actually quadratic (worst-case) in the number of nodes. It is very rare to come across any graph algorithm that is not BFS or DFS that is linear in the number of edges/nodes.

Comment: by linear i means O(V+E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of an MST in a directed graph is called an ***optimum branching*** or ***minimum-cost arborescence*** and there are several good algorithms for finding one. The most famous is probably the [Chu-Edmonds-Liu algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm), which can be implemented in time O(mn) in a straightforward way and time O(m + n log n) using more clever data structures.

Hope this helps!